# Match Digit in Regular Expressions (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following string:

```
str = '/house/0043214-123-Madison-Dr-Nashville-TN'
```

from which I need to capture the following digits

```
0043214
```

When I try

```
regexp_substr(str, '[\/house\/]\d+')
```

I get

```
/0043214
```

How do I get rid of the forward slash?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use `'\d+'`?

Comment: Because I want to make sure I capture any consecutive digits right after '/house/'.

Comment: Which is exactly what `'\d+'` does, for the test data you've given.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm):

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, '/house/(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
```

However, if it is always going to be the first number in the string then you could just do:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, '\d+' )
```

As an aside, `[abc]` will match any one character from `a`, `b` or `c`. So `[\/house\/]` does not match the string `/house/` but only a single character from it. If you remove the square bracketss and the unnecessary escape characters then you will match the string.